# Missing Style.Triggers and x:Type. Why?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, triggers

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyTextProperty}">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyTextProperty}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Hey, the text should not be empty!" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Question 1: Why is `<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">` giving the error `The type 'x:Type' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.`

Question 2: Why am I getting the error `The attachable property 'Triggers' was not found in type 'Style'.`

Am I missing anything ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use WPF XAML within Silverlight. Silverlight does not support the `{x:Type}` markup extension. You can instead use `TargetType={TextBox}`.

Also, Silverlight does not have `DataTrigger` support!

See:

[What is the replacement for DataTrigger in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529508/what-is-the-replacement-for-datatrigger-in-silverlight)

Comment: I'm having the same problem with x:Type ToggleButton, and I've tried your solution : TargetType="{ToggleButton}" but not I'm getting the error: Type 'ToggleButton' is used like a markup extension but does not derive from MarkupExtension. What does that mean ?

Comment: @Nada There should be TargetType="ToggleButton" without curly brackets