# Binding Button IsEnabled depending of the ComboBox selection

Tags: c#, silverlight, combobox

I'm sure this is really easy, but I don't know how do it.
I have a ComboBox and a Button, and I need to have the Button enabled only if the ComboBox has an item selected, i.e. if in the ComboBox has no elements showing, then the Button must be disabled.  How can I do this?

I have tried doing the following:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=mycombobox, Path=SelectedIndex}"/>
```

But it does not work.  I'm using Silverlight 5.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN has something that may be of help to you [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0cb86dbd-7809-4ea8-aafb-3b44d9c2ef4b/bind-combobox-selectedindex0-to-a-boolean-property?forum=wpf).  It suggests you use a converter or a data trigger.  I haven't tested this, but perhaps this will work?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=comboBox1}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ComboBox Name="comboBox1">
        <ComboBoxItem>One</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Two</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Three</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>

    <Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" Name="myButton" Content="Push me"/>
</Grid>
```

**EDIT**

I am under the impression that Cyndy has already figured all this out, but for any future readers...

As noted in the comments, you cannot do DataTriggers in Silverlight.  You'll need to do a converter.  [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/773f473c-ade6-4da5-946e-a09112297a82/binding-buttonisenabled-to-comboboxselecteditem?forum=wpf) is another post that may help.  In essence, you'll need to have your XAML set something like:

```
<Button Content="MyButton" IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=comboBox1, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}"/>
```

and then in your code-behind, you'll need something like:

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !(value == null);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: "{b:EvalBinding [lb.SelectedIndex] > -1}" is great! but it not Works in Silverlight...I'm working in a Converter, thanks so much!!

Comment: That part of the answer refers to a third-party binding extension.  Look at the section above it.

Comment: ok, I see, I try use it in Silverlight but some things are different `    <sdk:ChildWindow.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=comboBox1}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </sdk:ChildWindow.Resources>
` Style.Triggers not found and anything similar to this

Comment: I see--it appears Silverlight does not have DataTriggers as noted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529508/what-is-the-replacement-for-datatrigger-in-silverlight).  Sorry.  I guess you're stuck with writing a converter.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more efficient way to do it, but I'd simply determine whether the ComboBox.SelectedItem is null in the SelectedIndexChanged event.

Comment: Yes, it is the most simply, but I was want to do it in xaml, maybe with a Converter...ok, thanks so much, I evaluate the choices. Regards